# Passing parameters to a Grails exception handler

Tags: grails, exception

I have several methods in the same controller that explicitly catch the same exception, so I'm willing to replace them with Grails exception handlers, but I ran into an issue: the catch block in every controller logs a message with the context it was called with, something like this:

```
catch (WhateverException e) {
    response.status = HttpStatus.PROPER_HTTP_STATUS
    log.info("A whatever error occurred. Context = ${[foo: request.foo, bar: request.baz]}")
}
```

Thing is, the content of the context is different for every controller action even if the exceptions caught are the same.

Is there a way to pass the context as a parameter to a `whateverException` exception handler in order to remove the explicit catch blocks from every action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails does not directly allow this.

I still have a few ideas for you:

1. **use SLF4Js [Message Diagnostic Context (MDC)](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)**. Populate it inside the controller method that the exception is thrown in. Make sure that the MDC is included in the logback encoder (e.g. the `PatternLayoutEncoder` therefore offers a `%X`). Or even use a [Grails interceptor](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#interceptors) for populating the MDC with parameters common for all requests.
2. You can **access the `request` property also in Grails exception handler** methods. If the request attributes to log are always the same, only their values are different, that would be the most simple solution
3. If your Grails controllers are [prototype-scoped](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#_scoped_controllers), you can **assign the context to a controller field** and access that in the exception handler. Probably not the nicest solution.
4. Consider if your **exception cannot 'capture the context' and store it in one of its own fields**.

Quite often, I construct exceptions like this:

```
class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    final int field1
    final String field2

    MyException(int field1, String field2) {
        super("a message that includes $field1 and $field2")
        this.field1 = field1
        this.field2 = field2
    }
}
```

This way, the context (`field1`, `field2`) can be accessed in the exception handler as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Unfortunately, although all your solutions make sense, none of them seems viable to me. The best is probably #4, since exceptions are actually thrown by services called by the controller, but they are too generic and they have different context fields depending on the case. In the end, I think I'll go with a generic Map for the context inside the exceptions instead of specific fields.